# How to merge two flow files in one

Tags: apache-nifi

I need to design a Nifi structure that has receives two flow files containg:

1. An HTML template.
2. The informations that will substitute.
   Output is : An HTML ready to be used

Any ideas?

Edit: The idea here is to prepare a mail marketing campaign. For that I need to have all the metadata (in the attributes) and the html (in the content) to send to our providers API.

I use 3 files to build the campaign:

1. A CSV file with the variable fields (First Name, email address, unsubscribe link...)
2. Another CSV with the metadata (Sender name, sender address, template to be used...)
3. The HTML template (whose path came with the metadata)

So far I have a structure that is able to fetch all 3 files, integrate the first 2 in a series of flow files that represents each email to be sent.

However I'm having trouble with the last step that in my mind should be merging the email flow file with a copy of the template one (so I don't have to fetch the template repeatedly) and feeding the result into a ExecuteScript to do the actual rendering of the email.

Hope that's clear.

Comment: have you done anything yet ? put more details in

Comment: Added more details.

Comment: is there a connection between the metadata and the variables? (lookup), or do you have the  First Name, email address, unsubscribe link.. values already ?

Comment: There is no connection Up_one.

Comment: Is the template the same for all ? Or it depends on the campaign or email, program etc ?

Comment: Depends on campaign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

1. Read the in the information you want to substitute into the NiFi system.
2. Extract the information to substitute to FlowFile attributes
3. Get the HTML template into the FlowFile body
4. Use a processor to replace the important parts of the HTML template with your FlowFile Attributes

More detail in your question would be appreciated!

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do. However I can't figure out step 3.

Comment: @ViniciusZolinDeJesus How have you prepared your HTML template? Do you have it stored in a file, or you want to make it fresh inside NiFi?

Comment: I have it stored in a file that, on production, will be stored at S3

Comment: @ViniciusZolinDeJesus, still not clear what is the problem/question... for step 3 - if your template on S3 just use `FetchS3Object`. also you can store template in distributed cache or as a local file to avoid fetching template for each email.

Comment: The root problem here is just that. How to avoid re-fetching the template for each email.